# How to get information of directory that is mounted or not mounted using ansible?

Tags: ansible, mounted-volumes

So I am trying to get the facts from /tmp directory to get result of sized is being mounted or not and permission file. So I have used the find module, it gives me the result but not what I am looking for. 
For example: if my temp directory is 50gb and permission is 777, the result should show me the name of the directory, mounted size and permission code. So what I want is the full size of temp directory folder to be shown instead of each files of info.

```
- name: "get the facts"
  find:
    path: /tmp
    file_type: directory
    recurse: no
    size: 50g
  register: find_result
- name: "print the result"
  debug: var=find_result
```

Comment: Well, maybe the explanation is not clear enough, but what your are telling here is: given that I am a folder named `/tmp` of size 50Go with permission 777, print me the name, size and permission. Well then the answers will invariably be `/tmp; 50Go; 777`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *Get result of size, is being mounted or not, and permission.*

A: Use [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) to get size and permissions. Variable *`ansible_mounts`* is a list of the mount points. For example the play

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
    my_dir: /mnt
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ my_dir }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "size:{{ result.stat.size }} mode:{{ result.stat.mode }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_dir }} is mount-point"
      when: my_dir in ansible_mounts|json_query('[].mount')
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_dir }} is not mount-point"
      when: my_dir not in ansible_mounts|json_query('[].mount')
```

gives

```
"msg": "size:32768 mode:0755"
"msg": "/mnt is mount-point"
skipping: [localhost]
```

---

Notes

- Ansible will create the variable *`ansible_mounts`* if the variable *`gather_facts`* is set `True`.